# Migrate DotNetOpenAuth to ASP.NET Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net-identity, dotnetopenauth, asp.net-identity-2

I am using DotNetOpenAuth with Google's OpenId provider.

`OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient();`

I am in the process of migrating to ASP.NET Identity, but I see that ASP.NET uses Google's OpenAuth provider.

How do I properly migrate the from one to the other?

Comment: The best answer I found was here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26822529/1152054

Answer (score -1):

Follow this Blog

https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Creating-an-openid-relying-party-%28programatically%29

Maybe it solve you problem